# Django ModelAdmin admin_order_field with nulls_last

Tags: django, django-modeladmin

I am trying to sort column of `ModelAdmin` list field with `admin_order_field` with `nulls_last` such as:

```
class UserProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_sum_amount(self, obj):
          return obj.sum_amount
    get_sum_amount.admin_order_field = F('sum_amount').desc(nulls_last=True)
```

But I am getting following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/petr/.local/share/virtualenvs/aklub_project-HrPEZ5ak/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/petr/.local/share/virtualenvs/aklub_project-HrPEZ5ak/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/petr/.local/share/virtualenvs/aklub_project-HrPEZ5ak/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/petr/.local/share/virtualenvs/aklub_project-HrPEZ5ak/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 606, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/petr/.local/share/virtualenvs/aklub_project-HrPEZ5ak/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 142, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/petr/.local/share/virtualenvs/aklub_project-HrPEZ5ak/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/petr/.local/share/virtualenvs/aklub_project-HrPEZ5ak/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 223, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/petr/.local/share/virtualenvs/aklub_project-HrPEZ5ak/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 45, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/petr/.local/share/virtualenvs/aklub_project-HrPEZ5ak/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 142, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/petr/.local/share/virtualenvs/aklub_project-HrPEZ5ak/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1672, in changelist_view
    cl = self.get_changelist_instance(request)
  File "/home/petr/.local/share/virtualenvs/aklub_project-HrPEZ5ak/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 744, in get_changelist_instance
    sortable_by,
  File "/home/petr/.local/share/virtualenvs/aklub_project-HrPEZ5ak/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/views/main.py", line 81, in __init__
    self.queryset = self.get_queryset(request)
  File "/home/petr/.local/share/virtualenvs/aklub_project-HrPEZ5ak/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/views/main.py", line 436, in get_queryset
    qs = qs.order_by(*ordering)
  File "/home/petr/.local/share/virtualenvs/aklub_project-HrPEZ5ak/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1074, in order_by
    obj.query.add_ordering(*field_names)
  File "/home/petr/.local/share/virtualenvs/aklub_project-HrPEZ5ak/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1804, in add_ordering
    if not hasattr(item, 'resolve_expression') and not ORDER_PATTERN.match(item):
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

I am using Django 2.2. Is this issue in Django or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I found out, that this is not supported in current Django version: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/30981

Answer (score 0):

This is now possible in Django starting with version 3.1.